# ms sql server instance name is not resolved in wsl

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu, sqlalchemy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have have ms sql db server `someserver` with an instance `someinstance` installed listening on port `1435`

Normally I connect to the server using the following code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
import pandas as pd

server = 'someserver\someinstance' 
database = 'database' 
username = 'user'
password = 'secret'

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params, echo=True)

df=pd.read_sql("select * from xy",engine)
```

This works fine on most systems. However, on my Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS installed on wsl ist gives me the following error:

```
OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

When I change the server variable to include the port instead of the instance name (`server = 'someserver,1434'`) it works fine again.

So there seems to be a problem with the resolution of the instance name to the correct port. Any ideas where I have to look to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport

Comment: tcp/1434 is not the port you're looking for - it's the [Dedicated Admin Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators) and by default is only available on `localhost` to logins with the sysadmin role. What's likely happening is that the first letter of your instance name forms part of a Python [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#escape-sequences), so have you tried to escape the backslash with a backslash in your `server` string?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: yes you are right, that isn't the port. Exscaping leads to the same error

Comment: @GordThompson: That's what I was looking for. sqlserverport works fine when I use it in my windows environment. However on the wsl environment I get `BrowserError` `sqlserverport.lookup()`

Comment: `BrowserError` is often caused by a firewall blocking UDP traffic to the SQL Browser port (1434).